# Using Flask, Jinja2, HTML to update page on buttonpress

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm new to Flask / Jinja and a little confused.

I have an index.html file with a text input field, a button, and an unordered list. I also have a main.py file with some functions that take input.

When I press the button I want to take the text in the input field, pass the text to my python file (which will do some processing / API calls) and then pass the list back to the HTML file, without re-rendering the page. How do I accomplish this?

Here are my code snippets:

In index.html:

```
#This is where I want to get the input from 
<input type="text" style="text-align:center;">

#This is the button that should generate the list when I press it
<li><a href="#content" class="button big special">Search</a></li>
```

In main.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return 'Hello World!'

def doesArticleExist(topic):
    foundTopics = wikipedia.search(topic)
    if (len(foundTopics) > 0):
        return foundTopics
    return ["No topics were found! Your topic is new!"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a lot of documentation on Flask on the web that cover this kind of example. My suggestion is to start with a good tutorial. I can recommend Miguel Grinberg(http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) who also wrote a book and has done some very useful tutorials (see on YouTube).

Comment: [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program demonstrates one way to do a Wikipedia topic search. Note that this relies upon pure HTML. Thus, it re-renders the page each time the user clicks the button.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
import wikipedia

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret'

class WikiForm(Form):
    key = StringField('Search Term', validators=[DataRequired()])

index_html='''
<html><body>
<form method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.key.label }}: {{ form.key() }}
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
<hr />
{% if topics %}<ul>
    {% for topic in topics %}<li>{{ topic }}</li>{% endfor %}
</ul>{% endif %}
</body></html>
'''

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    form = WikiForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        topics = wikipedia.search(form.key.data) or ['No topic found']
        return render_template_string(index_html, topics=topics, form=form)
    return render_template_string(index_html, topics=None, form=form)

app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is an example that uses Javascript, including jQuery and AJAX. It updates the page without re-rendering, but it does require that the user have Javascript enabled.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request, jsonify
import wikipedia

app = Flask(__name__)

index_html='''
<html><body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type=text/javascript>
  function submit() {
    $.getJSON({{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }} + '/topics',
      { key: $('#key').val() },
      function(data) {
        var ul = $('#result');
        ul.empty();
        $(data.topics).each(function(index, item) {
          ul.append($('<li>',{text:item}));});});}
</script>
Search Term: <input id="key" name="key"/>
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Go" onclick="submit();" />
<hr /><ul id="result"></ul>
</body></html>'''

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string(index_html)

@app.route('/topics')
def topics():
    key = request.args.get('key')
    topics = wikipedia.search(key) or ['No topic found']
    return jsonify(topics=topics)

app.run(debug=True)
```

References:

- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/jquery/
- http://jquery.com/

Comment: Thanks! I think I have a much better understanding of what's going on now. Unfortunately, both of these implementations give me a chunking error -- but that's another question.